# Processing PDF files with Javascript-enhanced forms using Perl

Tags: javascript, perl, pdf, perl-module

**Task:** Add some data (say localtime) to PDF file (This PDF file contains form)

**Sample file:** http://www.immihelp.com/nri/forms/passport-application-form.pdf

I have tried 3 popular modules so far. [PDF::API2](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDF::API2), [CAM::PDF](https://metacpan.org/pod/CAM::PDF) and [PDF::Reuse](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDF::Reuse).

**Try 1:** [PDF::API2](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDF::API2)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use PDF::API2;
my $pdf = PDF::API2->open('form.pdf');
```

> Error: The PDF file uses a cross-reference stream, which is not yet
>   supported (see Know n Issues in the PDF::API2 documentation) at
>   C:\Perl\site\lib/PDF/API2/Basic/PDF/ File.pm line 1048.

**Try 2:** [CAM::PDF](https://metacpan.org/pod/CAM::PDF)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dump qw(dump);
use CAM::PDF;
my $pdf = CAM::PDF->new('form.pdf') or die "failed";
$pdf->appendPageContent(1, localtime);
$pdf->save();
```

> Error: This stream is too complex for me to write... Giving up

I checked the code and found this module does not support complex streams at the moment

[From PDF.pm](https://metacpan.org/source/CDOLAN/CAM-PDF-1.60/lib/CAM/PDF.pm)

```
# TODO: Handle more complex streams ...
 die "This stream is too complex for me to write... Giving up\n";
```

When I tried `cleanoutput` method instead of `save` it worked correctly, but on opening PDF I get the below message. I also observed that now I'm unable to enter data into the form.

Full image URL: https://i.stack.imgur.com/anAMW.png

[image]

**Try 3:** [PDF::Reuse](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDF::Reuse)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use PDF::Reuse;
prFile('output.pdf');
prForm("form.pdf");
prPage();
prText(100,100, localtime);
prEnd();
```

**Issue:** Above code correctly adds the data but 2nd page of the original PDF is no longer available in `output.pdf`.

I noticed that Merlyn (Randal L Schwartz) had also asked similar question on perlmonks (http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=556764).

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use PDF::Reuse;

prFile('output.pdf');

my $left_page = 1;
my $page_number = 1;

while ($left_page) {
    prForm("form.pdf", $page_number);
    # Fill data
    prText(100, 100, localtime) if $page_number == 1;

    $left_page = prSinglePage("form.pdf");
    $page_number ++
}

prEnd();
```